# Email cards shows correct time, Calendar does not

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-schemas

I've got my Event Card approved and working. The card in Gmail shows the correct time (10pm Berlin, DE) but on the Google calendar it shows as 7am.

When I create the card I convert the date from Berlin to UTC and return the date in ISO 8601 format:

```
$dt = new \DateTime($dateString, new \DateTimeZone($this->timezone ?? \Phpr::$config->get('TIMEZONE')));
$dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

return $dt->format("c");
```

and this is the resulting markup:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "EventReservation",
        "reservationNumber": "2400071",
        "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
        "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Some dude's name"
        },
        "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "Event",
            "name": "Demo Event Flux (1)",
            "startDate": "2022-05-07T22:00:00+10:00",
            "endDate": "2022-05-08T03:00:00+10:00",
            "url": "https://www.yyy.zzz/event/demo-event-fl-1",
            "location": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "name": "Berlin Central Station",
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "Europaplatz 1",
                    "addressLocality": "Berlin",
                    "addressRegion": "Berlin",
                    "postalCode": "10557",
                    "addressCountry": "DE"
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image: Card in Gmail and Calendar entry]

I'm not sure, but seems that this is a Calendar problem, not a schema problem.
Maybe Calendar doesn't have enough information to know the precise timezone?
Maybe my conversion is wrong.

Has this happened to you?
Thanks

Comment: You need to show us the input values that produce the output, the output produced, and what you _expected_ to be output. As it stands there's little we can suggest just by the input variable names.

Comment: The markup shows the data from the PHP converted date, the date in the markup shows fine in the card, but not in the calendar.

Comment: `"startDate": "2022-05-07T22:00:00+10:00"` is still 13:00 Berlin time. You have bad data or bad config in there _somewhere_ but there's no way to tell exactly _where_ without more information. For all I know the specific computer that is submitting the input data has an incorrect timezone and/or out-of-sync clock. ***The input needs to be validated as a baseline.***

Comment: That's something I can look into, thank you @Sammitch